# powershell -replace wont work when called by vba

Tags: regex, vba, powershell, outlook

I have a powershell script that replace some charatere from a string. The string look like this:
1234 - A Long Project Name
I need the string to replace space for underscore so it look like this:  1234_A_Long_Project_Name

This is part of my powershell code:

```
...
$projet = $projet -replace '\s+-\s+','_'  
$projet = $projet -replace '\s+|_+','_'
...
```

When I run this script directly in powershell it does what I want. The problem is that I need to call the script from a VBA macro in Outlook, when a mail is received with a particular subject this macro is fired:

```
sText = Split(olItem.Body, vbCrLf)
    Line = Split(sText(1), ":")
    If Line(0) = "Projet " Then
        projet = Trim(Line(1))
        retval = Shell("powershell -noexit c:\script\droit.ps1 '" & projet & "'")
    End If
```

If i run the script with the string "1234 - Long project Name" from powershell, is give me this:
1234_Long_Project_Name
When the script is fired by vba, with the same string, it return me this:
1234_-_Long_Project_Name

Anyone have an idea why it doesn't return me the same result.
Just for info, I run the script on Win 8.1, powerhsell 4 and outlook 2013.

Thank you all

Edit:
this is the powershell script:

```
Param([string]$projet)
function getPass2($adminName, $encrypted, $domain){
    $password = convertto-securestring -string $encrypted
    $Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $domain\$AdminName,$password
    $cred
}

$projet = $projet -replace '\s+-\s+','_'
$projet = $projet -replace '\s+|_+','_'
$projet = $projet -replace 'é|è|ê','e'
$projet = $projet -replace 'à','a'
$projet = $projet -replace 'ï','i'
$projet = $projet -replace 'ç','c'
$projet

$encrypted = "123"
$AdminName = "123"

$cred = getPass2 $adminName $encrypted "123"
$exist = $false

#commande for serve1
if ($cred){
    $session = New-PSSession -credential $cred -ComputerName "server"

    #ScriptBlock server1
    $result = Invoke-command -session $session  -Args $projet -ScriptBlock {
        $projet = $args[0]
        #folder copy
        if($projet){
            $SFolder = "z:\FolderTemplate\"
            $DFolder = "z:\DestinationFolder\" + $projet 
            $FileExists = Test-Path $DFolder
            if  ($FileExists -eq $false)
                {
                    Copy-Item $SFolder $DFolder -recurse

                    #acl
                    $SFolderList = get-childitem -name $SFolder -recurse
                    foreach ($Folder in $SFolderList) {
                              $SFullPath = $SFolder + "$Folder"
                              $DFullPath = $DFolder + "\" + "$Folder"
                          $NewACL = Get-ACL "$SFullPath"
                    Set-ACL "$DFullPath" $NewACL
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                    $exist = $true
                    return $exist
                }
        }
        else{
            echo "error"
        }s
    }
    Remove-PsSession -session $session
    $exist = $result


    #Credentiel someserver
    $AdminName = "123"
    $encrypted = "123"
    $credMTL = getPass2 $adminName $encrypted "123"
    #commande for some server
    if ($credMTL -and !$exist){
            $session = New-PSSession -credential $credMTL -ComputerName "server2"  
            $result = Invoke-command -session $session  -Args $projet -ScriptBlock {
                $projet = $args[0]
                $SFolder = "F:\Folder\template"
                $DFolder = "F:\destinationFolder\" + $projet 
                $FileExists = Test-Path $DFolder
                    if  ($FileExists -eq $false)
                        {
                            $shortcutName = $DFolder + "\someLink.lnk"
                            $shortcutTarget = "\\linkPath\" + $projet

                            Copy-Item $SFolder $DFolder -recurse

                            $shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
                            $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutName)
                            $shortcut.TargetPath = $shortcut.TargetPath + "\" + $projet
                            $shortcut.Description = $projet
                            $shortcut.Save()
                            $exist = $false
                        }
                    else {
                        $exist = $true
                        }
            return $exist
            }
            Remove-PsSession -session $session
    }
    return $result
}
```

Comment: From VBA (as from VB4/5/6 – VB before .NET) you can use the Windows Scripting runtime, which has a regex engine: see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2.aspx) (ignore the "web" in the section name: this is not limited to in browser scripting).

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer doing the string manipulation with Powershell, since the script will be run from other place too.

Comment: Show the parameter handling of your PowerShell script (i.e. how `projet` is assigned to `$projet`).

Comment: I edited the post with the entire script. Thank you

Comment: Did you try to debug VBA code? What is the actual value passed to the PS script?

Comment: I tried to repro this with VBScript and it worked fine.

Comment: Well it seems that it come from my test string. I tried i new email, and it worked out. dont know why, the text is exactly the same... Anyway thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finaly found what appened. When I wrote the test mail in outlook, the line was changed by the auto correct feature of Outlook and the "-" was change by something else (dont know the charater, it look like an "-" but a little bit longer).

When I receive an autogenerated mail from my prod machin, it actually work very well.

Thank you every one for your help.